# IntelliJ form snapshot fails with exception

Tags: intellij-idea

I created a simple project from scratch to test the form snapshot functionality.

The project has one source file and uses the defaults of File->New Project.  The source is:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize(400,300);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I get the following exception when I try to take a snap shot:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/designer/DesignerEditorPanelFacade
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.radComponents.RadComponent.createSnapshotComponent(RadComponent.java:742)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.radComponents.RadContainer.importSnapshotComponent(RadContainer.java:639)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.radComponents.RadComponent.createSnapshotComponent(RadComponent.java:752)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.snapShooter.SnapShooterDaemon$SuspendSwingRunnable.createFormSnapshot(SnapShooterDaemon.java:271)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.snapShooter.SnapShooterDaemon$SuspendSwingRunnable.doSnapshotCommand(SnapShooterDaemon.java:259)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.snapShooter.SnapShooterDaemon$SuspendSwingRunnable.run(SnapShooterDaemon.java:238)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.designer.DesignerEditorPanelFacade
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 32 more
```

I checked the box for "Enable capturing form snapshots" in the run configuration.

When I go to New->Form Snapshot I get this window:

[image: Snapshot Dialog]

When I click "Create Snapshot" I get the exception I mentioned above.

Any ideas why this is happening?  I have IDEA 14.1.4.  I ran "Check for Updates" to be sure there wasn't anything new for IDEA or the plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in IntelliJ IDEA: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132891